# connect two VMs and one VM to the internet

Tags: networking, virtualization, qemu

Disclaimer: My knowledge about networking as well as qemu is little to none.

I'm using QEMU to run a Debian VM that runs an application. For testing purposes I now want to create a second VM running Windows that is connected to the first VM so it can access it.

This, so far, is working. However, with the current setup, the Windows VM has no connection to the Internet. I'd like to change this, though, but without allowing the Debian VM to connect to the Internet.

The current setup is that a bridge is being created as well as a number of virtual network devices (tap) which are then added to the bridge. One of the tap devices (let's say it's `tap0`) is then used for the second VM (the other ones are used by the first VM).

My question now is: Does it make sense, i.e. is it possible, to configure the bridge `br0` such that only `tap0` can connect to the internet? If so, how can I go about doing that (utilities like `brctl` are available).

It is deliberate that the Debian VM can't access the internet and this needs to stay this way. From what I understand I could just add `eth0` to the bridge to allow Internet access, but can I restrict that to the Windows VM (e.g. `tap0`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would setup the Debian VM so that it just doesn't have its network device configured/setup. I would then bond the Windows VM network device to the network of the host system in a bridged configuration to device `br0`.

To disable a Linux system's network you can disable the network using this command:

```
$ sudo service network stop
```

You can also configure this service so that it's always off.

```
$ sudo insserv -r network
```

To reenable a service:

```
$ sudo insserv network
```

#### References

- [Debian Daemon Wiki Page](https://wiki.debian.org/Daemon)

Comment: Thansk for the reply. I still have to do `brctl addif br0 eth0`, don't I? I tried that (and didn't disable `network` on the Debian VM), but ended up having Internet access only on the Windows VM – both the Debian VM and the host system didn't. Am I missing something? I figured just adding `eth0` should allow internet access on all systems (host + both VMs).

Comment: @IngoBürk - hmm. You typically add each device for each VM to the bridge. So they're all "stacked" up on it. So if you did a `ifconfig -a` on the host you should see `br0` + 3 other devices. `eth0`, plus 2 others for the guest VMs. Omitting the device for the Debian VM should still leave the other systems with functioning internet. I'd double check that the routing is setup correctly on the host system. `route -n`. Make sure you have a default gateway (GW) route.

Comment: Thanks, turns out that with the setup was it was really all I needed was to add `-netdev user,id=user.0 -device e1000,netdev=user.0` to the windows vm and not further configuring the bridge (the tap device for intra-vm networking was already set up).